# Imgly plugin is not exporting captured image

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app built with angular. I have integrated Imgly in my app. But it is not working properly. After editing an image the plugin is not exporting that image. I have looked into many documentation's but haven't found any solution on this.

Method capturing image and opening Imgly plugin

```
captureImage2() {
if (this.usepicker) {
  this.filePickerRef.nativeElement;
  // this.filePickerRef.nativeElement.click();
  // return;
}
const options: CaptureImageOptions = { limit: 1 };
this.mediaCapture.captureImage(options).then(
  async (data: MediaFile[]) => {
    const fullPath = data[0].fullPath;
    const directoryPath = fullPath.substring(0, fullPath.lastIndexOf("/"));
    const fileName = fullPath.substring(fullPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    console.log(
      "File Details ======>>>>>>",
      fullPath,
      directoryPath,
      fileName
    );
    PESDK.openEditor(
      async (data1) => {
        console.log("REEEEEE =====> ", JSON.stringify(data1));
        await this.toProcessImage(data1.image);
        const check = await this.displayImage(data1.image);
        // console.log(check);
        this.onButtonClick(data1.image);
        // const dataURL = await this.file.readAsDataURL(data1.image, fileName);
        // console.log("DATA URL ======>>>>>>" + dataURL);

        data1
          .save()
          .then(async (sceneAsString) => {
            const file = {
              dataURI: sceneAsString,
              directory: this.dic,
            };
            const fileResponse = await UriFileUpload(file);
            if (fileResponse) {
              console.log("image UPLOADED", JSON.stringify(fileResponse));
              this.toastSer.success("uploaded");
              // this.uploadedList = [...this.uploadedList , fileResponse1];
              // console.log(this.uploadedList);
              this.updateFiles.next(fileResponse);
            } else {
              this.toastSer.error("Somthing went wrong!");
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Save failed", error);
          });
      },
      (error) => console.log(error),
      fullPath
    );

  },
  (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err)
);
```

}